# Cairo graphics: how to determine the physical screen dimensions

Tags: c, cairo

Writing code in C that must run on Raspbian but with the option of having various displays - from 128*64 to 1280*1024 and perhaps even larger. I want my program to begin by getting the physical dimensions of the display (in pixels) then decide what windows to create in it. The application is kind of kiosk , user interaction may not be a requirement, so the display must be right from the beginning.
Using Raspbian Stretch, Cairo over Gtk, gcc 6.3.0

Comment: I did find (on these same pages) width=gdk_screen_width();
height=gdk_screen_height(); but that gives a warning at compilation ("deprecated") and an error when ran ("assertion GDK_IS_SCREEN failed or some such)

Comment: Did you call `gtk_init`?

Answer (score 0):

More critical info is what gtk version you are using. If those are deprecated it is because gdk moved to per screen settings which you can get with functions such as:

gdk_display_get_n_monitors

gdk_get_monitor

gdk_monitor_get_geometry

GdkRectangle->width and/or ->height

These are in application pixels so you may need to scale.

At a guess the IS_SCREEN failure may be due to things not being initialised. Will need more info to know for sure.